# Error when running multiple PHPUnit Tests in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

Unit testing in a Laravel 8 project is throwing an error when more than one test is called.
The issue is causing my tests to fail when I run more than one at once. When running a batch of tests the first one runs and passes as expected, Then all subsequent tests fail when trying to run the `createApplication()` function from the default `trait CreatesApplication`. All of my tests have been run individually and pass.

Causing this error:

```
• Tests\Feature\ProjectDashboardTest > dashboard returns200
   Error

  Call to a member function make() on bool

  at tests/CreatesApplication.php:19
     15▕     public function createApplication()
     16▕     {
     17▕         $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
     18▕
  ➜  19▕         $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
     20▕
     21▕         return $app;
     22▕     }
     23▕ }
```

This occurs when the two tests run are identical.

So this code:

```
class DashboardTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testDashboardReturns200()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/dashboard');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function testDashboardReturns200V2()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/dashboard');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Gives this result:

```
php artisan test ./tests/feature/DashboardTest.php

   FAIL  Tests\Feature\DashboardTest
  ✓ dashboard returns200
  ⨯ dashboard returns200 v2

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\DashboardTest > dashboard returns200 v2
   Error

  Call to a member function make() on bool

  at tests/CreatesApplication.php:19
     15▕     public function createApplication()
     16▕     {
     17▕         $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
     18▕
  ➜  19▕         $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
     20▕
     21▕         return $app;
     22▕     }
     23▕ }


  Tests:  1 failed, 1 passed
  Time:   4.02s
```

Is there a fix I am missing?

**Edit, Added App file as requested**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;
```

Comment: Can you show your bootstrap/app.php file? `require_once` takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement. Then your `$app` is the return of the function giving you a `true`  as the include was probably successful. Then the error seems logical as you try to call make() from a boolean variable.

Comment: I've added the app file to the body of the question.

Comment: If you `var_dump($app)` inside `DashboardTest.php`, what does it show?

Comment: The first time it shows $app as a `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application` , The second test shows $app as `true`

Comment: What if you replace `require_once` with `require`?

Comment: That has fixed the issue! If you reply to the main question I'll mark it as resolved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you run `require_once`, the script isn't loaded a second time and will therefor return a boolean. Replace `require_once` with `require` to solve it.